# Record video of a specific program identified by its pid

Tags: windows, screen-recording

What's a good software to record as video a specific process?

What I want to do is record a session done via [Windows Remote Assistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Remote_Assistance) but I want to record *only* what happend in that process, not the entire desktop.

I'd like one easy to use, something you give the [`pid`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier) or so and the software start the recording automatically, without specific things like positions on screen I want to record. I want the entire process' Window to be recorded, regardless its position on size on screen and if possible, also when it's minimized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, it seems like [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) is a good fit for you. It was designed to stream video and sound over the internet, but if you go to Settings > Broadcast Settings, there's an option called "Save to file" which you can check to... well, save to a file. You can also fiddle with Mode, which should let you avoid streaming at all.

It's also even easier than providing a PID -- just click Edit Scene in the main screen, then add a source, and it's really easy from there. I don't know if it can record while minimized, if only because your platform may not render window updates when it's minimized, but that's fairly easy to test.

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like they have very much command-line interface support, but [there are a few options](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/parameters-command-line.9805/#post-188327) that I could find documented. You may see more if you look further through that thread or through the source.

According to some sleuthing by the OP, there's also a command line option, `--startrecording`, which starts recording (as opposed to streaming). See [the GitHub repo](https://github.com/jp9000/obs-studio/blob/master/obs/obs-app.cpp#L17870) if you want to try to glean some more info from it. Note that the link may not always point to exactly the right spot, due to the code being updated over time.

Comment: Put that edit in your question: on OBS studio there's exactly the flag I was looking for in the classic version: `--startrecording`! It's undocumented yet, but I found it in a very trustable source, the source code itself haha: https://github.com/jp9000/obs-studio/blob/master/obs/obs-app.cpp#L1787

Comment: You're welcome! give a link to point to a specific line on github may be an issue. We would rather tell the user look into main() function and see how and which are the arguments supported by the application

Comment: @Jack Even that wouldn't necessarily be correct -- it'd be trivial to refactor the code to move the argument parsing stuff out of the main method. This is good enough.